# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genism'

Tags: windows-7, installation, python

I have both Python 3.7 and miniconda3 on my windows 7, 64-bit. I tried installing gensim package in python using the following command

> pip3 install -U gensim

and I notice that it is getting installed in miniconda3 folder which is

> C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages

instead of

> C:\Users\sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages

I tried checking this in windows terminal by doing the following

> C:\Windows\System32>**pip3 install -U gensim**
>   Requirement already up-to-date: gensim in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (3.8.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: smart-open>=1.8.1 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.8.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.3 in c:\users\sree\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from gensim) (1.17.2)
>   Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.18.1 in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from gensim) (1.3.1)

Now the problem is I am getting the below error in Python shell when I try to run my code in Python IDLE

**import genism
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'genism'**

what exactly is causing this problem ?

Comment: `gensim` != `genism`

Answer (score 1):

`gensim` != `genism`.

It seems you have a typo in your code, it should be:

```
import gensim
```

Comment: No. it is correct. `import gensim` this is what it is

Comment: @dattasubrahmanyam: It seems your code have `import genism` but you should have `import gensim`

Comment: yes @Toto. After my initial mistake I installed gensim and tried `import gensim`. yet, I face the same issue i.e., `module not found` . After observing a bit keenly in IDLE, I found that the python path **is NOT** `C:\Users\sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages`. Now, I am even more confused as in what is my fault and what should I do !

Comment: Whatever way I try to install gensim, I am getting the same message which I've mentioned in the question which is Requirement already satisfied and it is pointing to miniconda3 folder, while the installation folder I am in is `C:\Users\sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages`, by doing a **cd target directory**. But the python path I see in IDLE is `C:\Users\Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages` 
and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the version of `pip3` installed in your path is associated with Miniconda (as you've noted).

To install a module for the Python version associated with your other installation, you need to use a version of `pip` installed in e.g. `C:\Users\sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\`

> I am getting [a `ModuleNotFound` error] in the Python shell when I try to run my code in Python IDLE.  [...]What exactly is causing this problem ?

It's likely the version of IDLE you are using isn't associated with your Miniconda installation (but rather your other Python installation). Python installations are typically separate, so they can't share modules. If you want to use a module in IDLE, you will probably need to install your desired module(s) to ex. `C:\Users\sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` with the correct version of `pip` (as mentioned above).

---

*Also, as outlined by @Toto in another answer, make certain you are spelling the package you wish to `import` correctly (i.e. `gensim` not `genism`).*

---

Comment: Now, I'm surprised to observe that the python path is `C:\Users\Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages` in my IDLE. So should I try changing installation directory to it and the try **C:\Users\Sree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages>pip3 install -U gensim.** ?? One more thing is the module name is infact **gensim**. there is no typo.

Comment: Now, considering your last instruction, I have pip3 in `C:\Users\Sree\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` and I tried installing the **gensim** module in this folder with pip3. Yet still I get the same error, which I have mentioned which is `Requirement already up-to-date: gensim in c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (3.8.1) `. Please help me fix this.